# The discursive nature of a concept

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, concept, reason

Concepts are universal, insofar as they are not individuated, and they are abstractions.
What does it really mean to say concepts are discursive?

Comment: Name any universal concept

Comment: Some more context, please...

Comment: who says that they are discursive?

Comment: If this refers to Kant's terminology he uses "discursive" for something mediated by partial representations, as opposed to "intuitive" that grasps objects directly. He often uses discursive/intuitive interchangeably with general/singular, but the terms emphasize different aspects. Since concepts are general they can only capture objects piecemeal, by representing features in them, while intuitions capture them as wholes. See e.g. [Watkins-Willaschek, Kant’s Account of Cognition](https://escholarship.org/content/qt11x016tq/qt11x016tq_noSplash_2bf4eaa52778243d6307ffb96f65143e.pdf?t=q569xz).

Comment: No context at all? Maybe Kant, as per comment above?